# How to post multiple sets of data as a single variable in an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I currently have a jQuery ajax function which posts a multi-dimensional array to my server.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Default.aspx/SaveQuoteProcesses",
  data: "{'items':" + JSON.stringify(jaggedArray) + "}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (msg){
    console.log('Success');
  },
  error: function (){
    console.log('Fail');
  }
});
```

Here is an example of the dataset I'm currently posting to the server:

```
[
    {"QpcOpsID":"22","QpcQitID":"63"},
    {"QpcOpsID":"20","QpcQitID":"63"},
    {"QpcOpsID":"26","QpcQitID":"63"},
    {"QpcOpsID":26,"QpcQitID":"63","QpcPprID":6,"PprQuestion":"How many colors?","AnswerValue":"4"}
]
```

I now need to send a regular array to the server in the same AJAX request.

```
["22", "20", "26"]
```

How can I include this new array in the existing javascript object?

Comment: Add a new property to the object??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var data = {
  items: jaggedArray,
  newArray: ["22", "20", "26"]
};
```

And then just `JSON.stringify(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the array as another property of the sent JSON -

```
data: "{'items':" + JSON.stringify(jaggedArray) + ",'additionalArray':"+JSON.stringify(YOUR_ARRAY)+"}",
```